# How to work with data that gets returned by an IEnumerable method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a simple view (paging, sorting and filtering).
The method I have that does that looks something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<VehicleMakeEntity> GetMake(int index, int count, 
                                      Expression<Func<VehicleMakeEntity, int>> orderLambda)
{
    var data = _makeRepository.SelectListMake(index, count, orderLambda).AsQueryable();
    return data;
}
```

You see it call another method from a repository, which looks the same

```
private readonly IQueryable<VehicleMakeEntity> _source;

public MakeRepository(ProjectDbContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
    _source = this.context.VehicleMake;
}

public IEnumerable<VehicleMakeEntity> SelectListMake(int index, int count, 
                                      Expression<Func<VehicleMakeEntity, int>> orderLambda)
{
    return _source.Skip(index * count).Take(count).OrderBy(orderLambda);
}
```

In my controller I call the method

```
public IActionResult Make()
{
    var data = _vehicleService.GetMake(1, 10, (p => p.Id));

    return View(data);
}
```

And it returns some data I do not know how to work with as seen here

[image]

I also generated a View based on that controller method, a basic List View which you can see here

```
@model IEnumerable<Data.Entities.VehicleMakeEntity>
@using NonFactors.Mvc.Grid;
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Make View";
}
<h2>Make View</h2>

<p>
<a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Abrv)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Abrv)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

But nothing is displaying on the site. Am I supposed to do something with the returned data? What am I doing wrong? I checked if the entities aren't getting the information from the database, they are.

Comment: How many records are in your db (your code returns records 11 to 20). And as a side note, your `.OrderBy()` should be before `.Skip()`

Comment: So _that_  was the problem. But why does it do that? I thought the second parameter limited how many records it pulls at a given time.

Comment: Because `index=1` and `.Skip(index * count)` equates to `.Skip(10)` which means start at record number 11

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with below code.

```
public IActionResult Make()
    {
        var data = _vehicleService.GetMake(1, 10, (p => p.Id)).ToList();

        return View(data);
    }
```

Also try to remove AsQueryable()

```
public IEnumerable<VehicleMakeEntity> GetMake(int index, int count, Expression<Func<VehicleMakeEntity, int>> orderLambda)
    {
        return _makeRepository.SelectListMake(index, count, orderLambda);
    }
```

Comment: I just did, it returns data Count = 0 now. It cannot be 0 as I foreached all the entities and they always return with the database value.

Comment: Ok, First check in repository with list. Getting any data from database.   public List<VehicleMakeEntity> SelectListMake(int index, int count, Expression<Func<VehicleMakeEntity, int>> orderLambda)
        {
            var VehicleMakeEntity = _source.Skip(index * count).Take(count).OrderBy(orderLambda).ToList();
            return VehicleMakeEntity;
        }

Comment: Check VehicleMakeEntity varible any list return or not.